# Detecting file type in linux using file managers module for detection files?

Tags: linux, types, detection, file-management

Is there a way to extract in bash or python file description from file manager (ex. PCManFM in lubuntu or any other like nautilus), because when I use command "find" or python-magic pkg or filemagic pkg, i do not get so accurate results like in file manager?
(for ex. when file contains gif header and php code under it, only file manager recognizes the file as PHP script, and other as gif image)

Comment: i know that python-magic and filemagic use libmagic for detection. TrID also gives me wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

found that [mimetypes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mimetype) is good choice. Nautilus uses it's database in /usr/share/mime/, python-magic and filemagic use libmagic, find uses something else i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use the linux [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command. I assume that file managers do the same (but I'm not 100% sure).

Examples:

```
file test.php   
# output: test.php: PHP script, ASCII text

file test.gif
# output: test.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 32 x 32

file /bin/ls
# output: /bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x37cdd635587f519989044055623abff939002027, stripped
```

Comment: i'm almost definitely sure that it's not using find, couse i tried in nautilus and PCManFM, and both of them show corretly. find command does not show correctly on some files

Comment: might be. can you give an example? (filetype: desired output) ?

Comment: ofc... http://pastebin.com/mvBjwD03
this is a php script with gif header. Desired output should be php script

Comment: Isn't it a gif? (with php tags in it).. I think this is more a feature than a lack of feature. But however, I've investigated a bit and couldn't find out a library which e.g. nautilus is using for that. But I'm sure it is possible to get that information. Would need more effort, e.g. reading the source code of nautilus

Comment: well since i'm trying to detect obfuscated files (malware) gif is not a good option for me. tnx for the effort!

Comment: Isn't `mimetype` the same as `file --mime-type` ?